# Why malloc(LLONG_MAX) complains but malloc(ULLONG_MAX) doesn't?

Tags: c, malloc

Case 1:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    void *mem = malloc(ULLONG_MAX); /* or ULONG_MAX */

    return 0;    
}
```

Case 2:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    void *mem = malloc(LLONG_MAX); /* or LONG_MAX */

    return 0;    
}
```

Both cases returns a NULL pointer and sets errno to 12 (ENOMEM), as expected. But in the latter, it actually complains about insufficient memory:

`long(5072) malloc: *** mmap(size=9223372036854775808) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

I'm just curious why that happens because ULLONG_MAX is bigger than LONG_MAX

System is Mac OS X 10.8.5, Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)

Comment: `ULLONG_MAX` probably overflows to an acceptable number for `malloc`.

Comment: `malloc()` may fail on `ULLONG_MAX` as the systems knows it is beyond any situation it can ever handle.  With the smaller value of `LLONG_MAX`, it may perceive it _might_ work and begin attempting the allocation, which also fails, but for a different reason.  Note: any allocation must allow indexing to `N+1` of type `size_t` and `ULLONG_MAX + 1` may overflow.

Comment: @RedAlert There's *no* way that the number passed to `malloc()` overflows ;-)

Comment: @BlueMoon even on system/compiler combinations where `sizeof(size_t) != sizeof(unsigned long long)`? I would think that, in that case, both values would be problematic, though... Also seems to be some confusion whether OP is referring to `LONG_MAX` or `LLONG_MAX`...

Comment: @twalberg The actual size of size_t doesn't matter. `size_t` is an unsigned type and an unsigned type can never overflow. When a value larger than what size_t can hold is assigned to size_t then reduction modulo of (TYPE_MAX+1) is taken and the result is well-defined. The behaviour OP sees depends on what resulting values are after such conversion.But AFAIAC, when malloc fails, returns 0 and sets errno, then that's more than enough. Any other diagnosis given can't be reasoned with (nothing more should be sent to stdout or stderr IMO) as it purely depends on specific implementation of malloc.

Comment: This all depends on what `sizeof(size_t)` is on your platform.

Comment: @BlueMoon IMHO it's clear that when people talk about unsigned types "overflowing" they mean the defined behaviour, even if they aren't using precise terminology

Comment: @BlueMoon the behavior you've described is still overflow, just well-defined overflow.

Comment: @MattMcNabb "Overflow" has a specific & well-defined meaning in C and to use to describe something else only adds to confusion especially to those who are new. Better word would be "wrap-around".

Comment: Title "Why malloc(LONG_MAX) ...." does not match code. `void *mem = malloc(LLONG_MAX); /* or LONG_MAX */`.  Title amended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument of `malloc` has type `size_t` which is some unsigned type.

From the error message about `mmap` failing, it is evident that your `malloc` is working with 64 bit sizes. So in fact your `size_t` is most likely the same type as `unsigned long long`.

In other words, it can represent the `ULLONG_MAX` value without overflow.  And it can also represent the `LLONG_MAX` value, which is about half that.

Your `malloc` function perhaps contains some safeguard logic which blocks it from actually issuing a `mmap` request when it is asked for 2**64-1 bytes; it just short-circuits to failing without even trying to allocate memory. But when it is "only" asked for 2**63-1 bytes, it issues the `mmap`, and so the request fails down in the kernel, causing a kernel log message.

You might want to also try `malloc(ULLONG_MAX - 1)` to see whether the safeguard is exactly for just the highest possible 64 bit unsigned value, or whether it extends to some lower range from there.

It makes sense for `malloc` to reject a range of sizes close to the maximum value of `size_t`, because such sizes are possibly the result of calculation error that led to wraparound.

(Of course, on small systems where `size_t` is 16 bits, `malloc` cannot do that: if the program asks for `65535` bytes, it probably means it.)